# Photoshop CC deletion and erasing is pixelated

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixelation

I'm having a problem I haven't encountered before. On my previous laptop I was using PSCC, and it was perfectly fine. But now, whenever I have a selection and delete, or try to erase using the brush, the edges become pixelated.

As an example-

Selection:
[image]

Cut to new layer:
[image]

What happened, and how can I fix this? I don't see any cut and paste options for selections anywhere to fiddle with, and changing the eraser to pencil mode isn't really much of a solution though it does do its one solitary job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layer mode is set to *Dissolve*.  Try setting it to *Normal*.

The Dissolve layer mode causes semi transparent pixels to look pixelated/dithered.

[image]

Comment: Oh my god, I didn't even notice >.<

Answer (score 0):

Had common problem...different reason. Maybe will help someone.

Image-> Mode-> Indexed Color...
-it was set like this causing pixelated,erasing,deleting etc.

Image-> Mode-> RGB Color   -this is right config.

[image: Picture show how it is different]